# Filter all rows from groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
| InvoiceNo | CategoryNo | Invoice Value | Item | Qty | Price |
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
|         1 |          1 |            77 |  128 |   1 |    10 |
|         1 |          1 |            77 |  101 |   1 |    11 |
|         1 |          2 |            77 |  105 |   3 |    12 |
|         1 |          3 |            77 |  129 |   2 |    10 |
|         2 |          1 |            21 |  145 |   1 |     9 |
|         2 |          2 |            21 |  130 |   1 |    12 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
```

I want to filter the entire group, if any of the items in the list `item_list = [128,129,130]` is present in that group, after grouping by `'InvoiceNo' &'CategoryNo'`.

My desired out put is as below

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
| InvoiceNo | CategoryNo | Invoice Value | Item | Qty | Price |
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
|         1 |          1 |            77 |  128 |   1 |    10 |
|         1 |          1 |            77 |  101 |   1 |    11 |
|         1 |          3 |            77 |  129 |   2 |    10 |
|         2 |          2 |            21 |  130 |   1 |    12 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------+
```

I know how to filter a dataframe using `isin()`. But, not sure how to do it with `groupby()`

so far i have tried below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

item_list = [128,129,130]

df.groupby(['InvoiceNo','CategoryNo'])['Item'].isin(item_list)
```

but nothing happens. please guide me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
s = (df['Item'].isin(item_list)
       .groupby([df['InvoiceNo'], df['CategoryNo']])
       .transform('any')
    )

df[s]
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But, i didn't understand what `transform('any')` is doing here

Comment: `transform` applies the function (`'any'`) on the whole group, and returns the same value to **all** rows within that group. In this case, if `any` item is in the list, all rows in that group are marked as `True`.